how i can map 2 collections of mongo to .net
I have a class that is part of another class but this class contains two list:
public class ChildrenMapMetadata
{
    public List<GroupMapMetadata> Groups { get; set; }

    public List<RoomMapMetadata> Rooms { get; set; }
}

and mi GroupMapMetadata class have this:
public class DbGroupMapMetadata
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid ParentMapId { get; set; }

    public string ObjectId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsGroup { get; set; }

    internal static void Build(BsonClassMap<DbGroupMapMetadata> classMap)
    {
        classMap.AutoMap();
        classMap.SetDiscriminator(nameof(DbGroupMapMetadata));
        classMap.SetDiscriminatorIsRequired(true);
        classMap.MapIdMember(mapMetadata => mapMetadata.Id)
            .SetIdGenerator(new GuidGenerator())
            .SetSerializer(new GuidSerializer(BsonType.String));
        classMap.MapMember(mapMetadata => mapMetadata.ParentMapId)
            .SetSerializer(new GuidSerializer(BsonType.String));
        classMap.MapMember(mapMetadata => mapMetadata.ObjectId);
        classMap.MapMember(mapMetadata => mapMetadata.Name);
        classMap.MapMember(mapMetadata => mapMetadata.IsGroup);
    }
}

My principal class for get data from mongo looks like this:
public class DbMapMetadata
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string NameGLB { get; set; }

    public bool IsInitialMap { get; set; }

    public bool HasPortals { get; set; }

    public bool HasChildren { get; set; }

    public List<DbPortalMapMetadata> Portals { get; set; }

    public Guid? ParentMap { get; set; }

    public DbChildrenMapMetadata Children { get; set; }

    internal static void Build(BsonClassMap<DbMapMetadata> classMap)
    {
        classMap.AutoMap();
        classMap.SetDiscriminator(nameof(DbMapMetadata));
        classMap.SetDiscriminatorIsRequired(true);
        classMap.MapIdMember(mapMetadata => mapMetadata.Id)
            .SetIdGenerator(new GuidGenerator())
            .SetSerializer(new GuidSerializer(BsonType.String));
        classMap.MapMember(mapMetadata => mapMetadata.ParentMap)
            .SetSerializer(new NullableSerializer<Guid>(new GuidSerializer(BsonType.String)));
    }
}

For make the Mapper from mongo to c# I use this:
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;
using Overlord.Modules.GeoMap.Infrastructure.MongoDb.Entities;
using Overlord.Shared.Infrastructure.MongoDb.Abstractions;

namespace Overlord.Modules.GeoMap.Infrastructure.MongoDb.Context;

public class MetadataDbContext(IMongoDatabase database) : DbContextBase(database)
{
    public IMongoCollection<DbMapMetadata> MapMetadata { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring()
    {
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<DbMapMetadata>(classMap => DbMapMetadata.Build(classMap));
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<DbPortalMapMetadata>(classMap => DbPortalMapMetadata.Build(classMap));
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<DbChildrenMapMetadata>(classMap => DbChildrenMapMetadata.Build(classMap));
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<DbGroupMapMetadata>(classMap => DbGroupMapMetadata.Build(classMap));
        BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<DbRoomMapMetadata>(classMap => DbRoomMapMetadata.Build(classMap));
    }
}

error:

System.FormatException: 'An error occurred while deserializing the
Children property of class
Overlord.Modules.GeoMap.Infrastructure.MongoDb.Entities.DbMapMetadata:
An error occurred while deserializing the Groups property of class
Overlord.Modules.GeoMap.Infrastructure.MongoDb.Entities.DbChildrenMapMetadata:
Element 'Id' does not match any field or property of class
Overlord.Modules.GeoMap.Infrastructure.MongoDb.Entities.DbGroupMapMetadata.'

and my question:

How can I map this correctly so that the data is associated correctly
and I don't get the error?

